# Comparing list of lists with dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

Hi please how can i compare the elements in dots with the keys in pos and print the pos[values] ie the tuples for those that are a match. Thank you

I tried this

```
dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}

 dot_pos = []
for k in dots:
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
            dot_pos.append(pos[key])
```

and got this error:

```
    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Just an update please

How then can I resolve this to get outputs like this:

```
[[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)],[ (0, 28), (7, 5]]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are supposed to be comparing. how are the values supposed to be related?

Comment: can you provide expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. you are using key in last line of the code, which is not defined.

```
dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}

dot_pos = []
for k in dots:
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
            dot_pos.append(pos[item])
```

For your second question in comment, this should work:

```
dot_pos = []
for k in dots:
    dot_new = []  
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
            dot_new.append(pos[item]) #Append the matches to a new list
    dot_pos.append(dot_new)
```

Comment: thanks for your previous help, please if I need to return those tuples within list ie output will be [[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)], [(0, 28), (7, 5)]] indicating that 3 items match from the first list in dots and only two in the second, how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in dots:

    for item in i:

        if(item in pos.keys()):

            print(pos[item])
```

Ans:
(0, 6)
(4, 3)
(9, 0)
(0, 28)
(7, 5)

Comment: thanks for your previous help, please if I need to return those tuples within list ie output will be [[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)], [(0, 28), (7, 5)]] indicating that 3 items match from the first list in dots and only two in the second, how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

```
l=list();
for i in dots:
    a=[]; // one list per element (which is list) in dots
    for item in i:
        if item in pos.keys():
            a.append(pos[item]);
    l.append(a)
```

// print(l)

// [[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)], [(0, 28), (7, 5)]]

Comment: hope this helps you out.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for ??

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can directly extract the points using comprehension. For example, if you have:

```
In [44]: pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}
In [45]: dots1 = [1,2,73,4]
In [46]: [pos[dot] for dot in dots1 if dot in pos.keys()]
Out[46]: [(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)]
```

Hence, if you have a temporary function that does that:

```
In [49]: def f(dots1): return [pos[dot] for dot in dots1 if dot in pos.keys()]
```

Then you can just map the function to dots ...

```
In [50]: f(dots1)
Out[50]: [(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)]
In [51]: dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
In [52]: map(f, dots)
Out[52]: [[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)], [(0, 28), (7, 5)]]
```